# How to get "hardware time"

Tags: c++, windows, time

I'm trying to create a license system that compares the license validness time to computer time. I'd like to get the times directly from the "hardware" so that it is not possible to trick the license sytem by changing the OS (Windows) time.

I've tried googling but maybe I don't know the right keywords. Different time APIs that I've checked do not state clearly whether they rely on OS or not.

What API would you use for this problem?

Comment: You want to trust a machine you don't have full control over to tell you the time? (hint: Windows gets the time from the hardware)

Comment: I'd advise checking the current system time to that of a web-service (NTP maybe). The fact is that the `hardware` clock value is what the OS is returning, or at-least that's what the OS would want you to believe. It can be faked easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing prevents a user from changing the hardware (BIOS) time. So, if you want to rely on the hardware, you can trust the Windows system time as well.

One approach could be to consult a NTP time server. But to be really sure, you must setup or use an NTP server, which authenticates itself.

See [NTP FAQ Authentication](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config-adv.htm#S-CONFIG-ADV-AUTH) for more.

But also keep in mind, this only works, as long as there is a network connection. If the user pulls the network cable or switches off the router, this approach will fail.

Comment: Good answer, thanks! I had clearly missed the trivial connection between BIOS time and Windows time :-) Luckily I can assume that user can't change the BIOS time. In future the approach with NTP server and authentication may be the way to go.

Comment: @kullero Changing the Windows time changes the "BIOS time" as well... If you can assume the user can't change one, you can assume it can't change the other, no?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Really?! Well, that isn't obvious for me. I thought that BIOS is separated from the operating system and one needs to enter BIOS and maybe give BIOS password to be able to change the BIOS time. I was assuming that the user has not the BIOS password and thus cannot change the BIOS time. So I wasn't right? Confused :-)

Comment: @kullero I just searched around, but couldn't find any official source. It seems the default behaviour is to change the hardware clock, but there seem to be some registry hacks to prevent this.

Comment: I'll give up my original idea of absolutte time stamps and use the Windows/BIOS time, i.e. trust the user ;-)